# Uniform limit of a sequence in $C_{c}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is in $C_{c}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $(f_k)$ be a sequence in $C_{c}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ the space of continuous functions with compact support from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}.$Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which containts $\mathrm{supp}(f_k)$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ If $f_k\rightarrow f$ uniformly then $f\in C_{c}^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Because the uniform limit of continuous functions is a continuous function it remains to show $f$ has compact support, so is enough to prove that $\mathrm{supp}(f)\subset K;$ here I am having problems.

If $x\in K^c$  then $f_k(x) = 0$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N},$ and $f_k(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ implies $f(x)=0,$ but I cannot see how to ensure $x\notin\mathrm{supp}(f).$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: If there is a compact $K$ s.t. $supp(f_k)\subset K$ for all $k$, then the result is rather obvious that $supp(f)\subset K$. There is nothing to prove...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what worries you is the possibility that $x$ might be in the closure of the set $\{y\in\mathbb{R^n}: f(y)\ne 0\}$? Well, it can't be the case. You proved that for each $x\notin K$ we have $f(x)=0$. Hence $\{y: f(y)\ne 0\}\subseteq K$. But remember that $K$ is compact, hence closed. So:

supp$(f)=\overline{\{y: f(y)\ne 0\}}\subseteq K$

Comment: Of course! Thanks @Mark.